# Selecting element via getElementById() vs var speed

Tags: javascript

Could someone pls explain why selecting element through variable is faster than just using DOM query getElementById()?
As I understand in the first case we ask interpreter to look through DOM tree for an element whose id is 'box' and once found interpreter returns its address. In the second case we store the address in variable first and then if we want to select the element we still need to lookup  a var with the address that we need. So how looking up a var is faster than looking up the element itself?

```
//1
getElementById('box');

//2
var itemOne = getElementById('box');
itemOne;
```

Comment: It's not faster in your example, but when reusing the variable, you've already the reference in a variable, and you don't need an extra DOM traversing step.

Comment: How are you taking such a measurement? In the code you posted you call getElementById() two times with the same arguments so the second time some caching improvement may be involved. Storing the result in a variable has no meaningful delay and, if you are going to use that value several times, it will be MUCH faster to use that variable than calling getElementById() every time...

Comment: @bitifet you mean DOM as a whole is stored in main memory vs var will rather be stored in CPU cache and hence the time to retrieve is greatly different? Do I get it right?

Comment: A short answer: [Object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-type) properties are not referring directly to the memory, they are searched from the object (which is like a look-up table, details are implementation-dependent). When getting an element from the DOM, you actually has to find `document.getElementById` function first, then it will traverse the DOM to find an element corresponding to the passed argument. But the DOM is a huge object, and searching a specific element takes time. To fully understand how a JS object finds its properties, you could read a book or two, for every engine.

Comment: @Stunt-man-mike absolutely NOT (I even doesn't understand what you meant). But I didn't talk about any cpu cache but `getElementById()`'s function internal cache.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `getElementById` it parses the DOM every time you run it. Once you allocate memory and store the result, the parsing is no longer needed, and the result is retrieved directly from the memory. I assume that's why it's faster.